# OpenCV function for computing optical flow for a better quality result

Tags: opencv, opticalflow

[image]I have used the below functions to compute optical flow on my research to extract the foreground object from a sequence of frames or video:

- cvGoodFeaturesToTrack()
- createOptFlow_DualTVL1()
- calcOpticalFlowFarneback()
- cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK()

So far I'm able to get acceptable result only from “`createOptFlow_DualTVL1()`” and now I want to improve the quality of the extracted foreground object especially on the border area.

Can anyone recommend any other OpenCV function for computing optical flow for a better quality result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show some sample images of the "bad" result you are getting together with the name of the algorithm and parameters used for computing that result? Sometimes it is due to the values of the parameters and the content of the image that give the bad results i.e., certain optical flow algorithms work better for some kind of images and the parameters have to be tuned accordingly. Also, this will give people the idea on the cases your algorithm are currently failing t and suggest appropriate ones for them.

Comment: As you can see on 3rd image there is some artifact on the foreground object which is extracted using opticalflow from the top two frames. here is the major code i used to compute the optical flow
Mat_<Point2f> Optical_Flow;
Ptr<DenseOpticalFlow> tvl1 = createOptFlow_DualTVL1();
tvl1->calc(New_Previous_Gray, New_Current_Gray, Optical_Flow);